# Yocto bitbake package group

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, yocto

I'm facing this problem.
When I bitbake recipeA and recipeB separately, everything works fine.

```
bitbake recipeA
bitbake recipeB
```

What I want to do is to group recipeA and recipeB into a package group

```
inherit packagegroup
PACKAGES  ="\
     packagegroup-my-package \
     "
RDEPENDS_${PN} += " \
     recipeA \
     recipeB \
     "
```

After that

```
bitbake packagegroup-my-package
```

Now begins my problems.
All my processed recipes results remains in WORKDIR instead of going to DEPLOIDYR as expected, do_install is not processed (I suppose).

In first case execution, when I bitbake every recipe all my result are copied in to DEPLOYDIR, do_install is processed.

Thank you in advance for your support.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add it to your local.conf or to your image recipe file to install it.

in the packagegroup class (which your recipe inherits) we clearly find :

```
# We only need the packaging tasks - disable the rest
deltask do_fetch
deltask do_unpack
deltask do_patch
deltask do_configure
deltask do_compile
deltask do_install
deltask do_populate_sysroot
```

I hope it helps you understand that.